# How can I clean the WordPress code?

Tags: wordpress, code-formatting

I'm looking for some tips to clean the code which is generated by WordPress and some plug-ins, because I'm not happy with the code generated by WordPress for two reasons:

1. The code isn't well formatted. I know, I know... It isn't important since that the browsers don't need to "parse" a well formatted code. However, I like to keep all codes well formatted and it includes HTML code generated by me or third-part systems.
2. Unfortunately, some parts of the code that WordPress puts on the `<head>` aren't well formatted and in some cases those parts aren't really necessary. By the way, I have no idea about how to clean-up it or how to hook the function which prints that code.

Is there some way to add tabs / spaces to the code generated by WordPress without change the core files / code?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're worrying about specifically the formatting of the code, i.e. tab indent levels, you're worrying too much. The only thing you should worry about at all is the readability of the code in files you actually edit on at at all regular basis, like some of your template files perhaps. The format of code sent to the browser has zero importance.

Answer (score 0):

Overlooking the overall ambiguity of your question, the file you need to edit to fix the `<head>` element is header.php. You will find it in your theme's folder in wp-contents.